# Is a website banner asking for permission to store cookies required?

Tags: cookies, rules

I see many websites put banners on top of their website telling you they want to store cookies on your machine. I don't understand why they would do this, is it a law? I read on wikipedea that the "European Union" passed some law about this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#EU_Cookie_Law), do I only have to follow the law if my website is being hosted there? if I own a website, should I put a banner a the top also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *technical* requirement that would require this type of banner to be displayed. The only requirements that might drive this type of UI decision are:

- Legal requirements, such as when a website is hosted in a certain jurisdiction, as you said.
- *Ethical decisions* by the company: the company may decide, even if they are not strictly required to notify the user, that they would **like to** notify the user that they are storing cookies, because they feel that it is a responsible or morally correct thing to do. For example, if I have a camera monitoring my private property, I am not *required* to put up a sign letting you know that; but if I choose to put up such a sign for your information, I might want to do that because I feel it is a responsible thing to do.

For those wondering, you can see an example of the kind of "banner" the querant is talking about on a very prominent and legitimate website, such as [Ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com).

Despite having provided all of this information, I don't think it is extremely topical to SuperUser to discuss the legal obligations of website owners, so my answer will not provide a detailed account of which jurisdictions may require this, or other details about law. As they say, "IANAL" (I am not a lawyer).

Answer (score 1):

In the US, you aren't 'required' to put any notice. However, any legitimate web site will put how they store and use cookies in their Privacy Policy.